# How to stop post-crash message in foobar2000?

Tags: windows, foobar2000

I'd like to get rid of the pop-up message when starting foobar2000 after crash.  Here are the steps to reproduce the message:

1. start foobar2000
2. start Task Manager, find foobar2000 process and end the process
3. start foobar2000 again

Result: it shows the message with text "foobar2000 was terminated abnormally last time."

What I want is for the program to start normally, without this message.  (The reason being when I restart Windows, it evidently cannot stop the programs in a clean way.  So this message means nothing substantial but an annoyance and a wasted click for me.)

My environment: Windows 7, foobar2000 1.1.10 (but been seeing that message since at least 1.1.8).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you report this problem to the team that works on foobar2000?  If this is actually a message generated by foobar2000, then what you want might not be possible, your limited to what the program is programmed to do.

Comment: Maybe investigate why foobar2000 terminates in an unclean way. It shouldn't happen.

Answer (score 2):

For portable foobar. Make **run.bat** in foobar2000 folder

**run.bat**

```
IF EXIST running del running
start C:\foobar2000\foobar2000.exe
exit
```

Comment: Note the warning is there with a reason. For example changes to your playlist might have been lost.